# "...in the past has launched recycling efforts..."

Tags: grammar

Just read this article:

https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/global-plastic-dow-shoes/

The first sentence of the fifth paragraph caught my eye:

*"Dow, a major producer of chemicals used to make plastics and other synthetic materials, in the past has launched recycling efforts that have fallen short of their stated aims. "*

This part confuses me:

*"...in the past **has** launched..."*

*"...in the past **had** launched..."*

Both seems correct. Does using "has" mean the recycling effort was launched in the past and continues today whereas using "had" means it was launched in the past and there's no certainty it still exists in the present? At this point I can't really tell the difference anymore. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is generally reserved for an event that occurred before another event in the past. Because there is no mention of any past event before the word that you're asking about, the past perfect would be inappropriate. (Of course, it might be appropriate if the reference event were described in the previous sentence. Because this is the first sentence of a paragraph, however, that's unlikely.)

> Does using "has" mean the recycling effort was launched in the past and continues today

Not necessarily. In fact, if the efforts fell short of their stated aims, then I'd suspect that they don't continue today. The present perfect is justified because there is no specific time for the event. ("In the past" is very vague.)